# Why RadioButtonFor userInput not binding to model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

When user selects the radioButton, `IsSelected` property is still `false` on postback, why?

**View**

[image]

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>UserChoice</legend>

        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsSelected)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)

        @Html.RadioButtonFor(uc => uc.IsSelected, false)

        <input type="submit" name="name" value="Submit Form" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Controller**

[image]

Comment: Do you realise that if you only have one radio button, it can't be unselected (unless the initial state is unselected). Did you instead mean to use a checkbox? A radio button is usually used to pick between a couple of options, e.g. Yes/No/Maybe you would create 3 radio buttons for the property with those 3 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have different types of option you could use following

A very simple way of implementing this would be something like this

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem =>item.SelectedOption, "Option1")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem =>item.SelectedOption, "Option2")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem =>item.SelectedOption, "Option3")
```

or you can also use,

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem =>item.SelectedOption, item.Option1)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem =>item.SelectedOption, item.Option2)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem =>item.SelectedOption, item.Option3)
```

If you just want `isSelected` is `true` or `false` use this.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(uc => uc.IsSelected, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if that your issue but if it checked than you expect to get false try makink the value true

```
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(uc => uc.IsSelected, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

[The overload that you are using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee830410%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) binds the value of the `radio` input element to the provided value - so you are generating markup like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="isSelected" value="false">
```

When this gets submitted back to your controller .NET deserializes that `value` to a `boolean` - which in this case, is `false`.

To fix it, use `true` as the second argument:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(uc => uc.IsSelected, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(uc => uc.IsSelected, true)
```

or

```
 @Html.RadioButton("IsSelected", true)
```